# local minima and first derivative

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives, optimization

I would want to follow the proof of the statement:

> If a twice differentiable function $f: S\mapsto \mathbb{R}$ with $S \subset \mathbb{R}$ being an open set has a local minima at point $x$ then $f'(x) =0 $.

The author proofs this by *contraposition* ($f'(x) \neq 0 $) in the following way:

> One wants to show: $\forall \epsilon  >0:\exists u \in S \cap U_\epsilon (x):f(u)<f(x)$
>
> 1. Starting with $f(x+h) = f(x) + f'(x)h + o(h) $, and using small
>    o-notation one gets to $\forall \eta >0: \exists  \delta >0: \forall h \in \mathbb{R}$
>    with $|h| <\delta $ such that $ \frac{f(x+h) -f(x) - f'(x)h }{h} <
>    \eta $
> 2. Leading to $ f(x+h) - f(x) - f'(x)h< |\eta h| \iff  f(x+h) < f(x) + f'(x)h \pm \eta h$
> 3. Now he chooses $\eta := \frac{1}{2}|f'(x)|>0$ and h, with $f'(x)h <0 $ and $|h| < min(\delta,\eta)$ with
>    $h \in S \cap U_\epsilon $ such that  $f(x+h) < f(x) + (f'(x) \pm
>     \eta)h \le f(x) + \frac{1}{2}f'(x)h < f(x)$

I find it difficult to follow this proof and would have the following questions :

1. In step 2, why can one replace the absolute value with a plus-minus
2. In step 3, how does this imply that there is such a h for every $\epsilon  >0$ and why is it neccesary to define such a $\eta$ with $|h| < min(\delta,\eta)$

Comment: The statement seems strange. To prove that if $x$ is a local extrema, then $f'(x) =0$, one only need to assume that $f$ is differentiable. So the statement is true but asks for unnecessary hypothesis, unless I am missing something

Comment: There is a simpler proof. It is easy to prove that if $f’(x) > 0$, then $f$ is strictly increasing near $x$ and if $f’(x) < 0$, then $f$ is strictly decreasing near $x$. Therefore, if $f$ is neither strictly increasing nor strictly decreasing at $x$, $f’(x)=0$.